# Which probability distribution returns a random value between 0 and 1?

Tags: distributions

Is there a probability distribution which result in the equal chance of a variable being anywhere between 0 and 1? Basically, the PDF function would look flat everywhere between 0 and 1 and a 0 everywhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called the (continuous) standard uniform distribution.

The general case is the continuous uniform over the interval $(a,b)$:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)

and if you set $a=0$ and $b=1$ (the unit interval) that special case is the standard uniform:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Standard_uniform

As Nick Cox mentioned in comments, the uniform may sometimes be called *rectangular* or *flat*.

[Note that your title is ambiguous - there's an infinity of distributions on the unit interval that can give 'a random value'; something may be random without equal-length subintervals being equiprobable.]

Comment: Other names I've seen are rectangular and flat.